# What is xutils.h, and what cflags/libs/packages do I need?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk2, wnck

I am thinking about maybe creating my own modified version of a GTK2 libwnck widget. In the source files of these widgets, it includes a file called `xutils.h`. This header file is present in GNOME's libwnck git repository, but it is not present in my distro's libwnck header files.

I have tried searching for an `xutils` package for Arch Linux, but I cannot find such a package. I also looked in Fedora's libwnck header files, and that does not have an `xutils.h` file either.

Here are my questions:

- What cflags/libs do I need in order to use this header file, or else what packages do I need to install?
- Why is the `xutils.h` file not present in my distro's libwnck header files?

This program should be able to be linked against a distro's stock libraries. Potential users should not be expected to download and compile other libwnck source files.

Please note that the header file I am looking for is called `xutils.h` (with an "s"), not `Xutil.h`.

Comment: `xutils.h` is a **private** header file contained in `libwnck`. You will not find it anywhere but in the libwnck tarball because it is used only during its compilation.

Comment: @ntd So, how do I compile these widgets separately from `libwnck`? Can I just copy the `xutils.h` file into my source directory and link my widgets against my distro's stock `libwnck`? Or would I need to compile the `xutils.c` source file into my binary?

Comment: You should pull into your source tree everything needed by the code you are using. And this does not mean only `xutils.c`... more likely you should import a big chunk of the libwnck project. Why not just fork it?

Comment: @ntd So, is it not possible to simply pull in a single header file and link my program against stock libwnck? When you say "fork", do you mean that I should fork the entire libwnck project?

Comment: You could try but I'd not hold my breath.  Be sure to at least match the versions of your `xutils.h` with the one installed. I think a fork (yes, I mean fork the whole libwcnk project) is much cleaner but better would be to start your widget from the ground (or inheriting from an existing one) and leverage the non-UI part of libwnck.

Answer (score -1):

I don't claim to know anything, but a quick google suggests that `xutils.h` is related to the X11 client side library, <s>and that it comes with the `libx11` package on Arch.</s>

This google link [xutils.h](http://code.google.com/p/avant-window-navigator/source/browse/trunk/src/xutils.h?r=157) still hints at an X11 related function, and it is interesting that the guards on the file are `WNCK_XUTILS_H`

Comment: I had a look at the file list for `libX11`, and I could see a file called `Xutil.h`, but not `xutils.h`.

Comment: @adlo1 Well there was that disclaimer I wrote.  But yeah .. I missed that minor difference.

Comment: Also, I would probably expect the header file to be in `/usr/include/libwnck-1.0/libwnck` rather than `/usr/include/X11`.

Comment: @adlo1 Given my ignorance, all I can say for certain is that it *is* X11 related somehow.